# How to find Genotype, from list of mutations:lineage list?

Tags: genomics, covid-19, sars-cov-2, python

I'm very new to python and I'm getting along nicely (I'd like to believe); however, I must be missing something here. I'm looking to read each and every file and compare each line against one another.

The aim of this is to see if any mutations are shared in any of the strains - to determine the genotype.

The inner-workings of the files are single spaced headers, as those you would find on GISAID.

`os.chdir("C:)`

````
with open('A D614G.txt', 'r') as file2:
with open('A E780Q.txt', 'r') as file3:
with open('A G476S.txt', 'r') as file4:
with open('A L18F.txt', 'r') as file5:
with open('A N439K.txt', 'r') as file6:
with open('A S477N.txt', 'r') as file7:
with open('A T478I.txt', 'r') as file8:
with open('A V483A.txt', 'r') as file9:
                               
files = [file1, file2, file3,file4, file5, file6, file7, file8, file9]

it = itertools.permutations((files), len(files))

for x in it:
    print(x)

os.chdir("C:)
with open('tester.txt', 'wt') as file_out:
    for x in it: 
        file_out.write()```

1 I recieve the following error on a very long repeated stretch of text

```<_io.TextIOWrapper name='A G476S.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>```
````

Comment: I seem to have worked it out - I shall post the working code for anyone interested. If anyone would like to streamline or test for efficiency please feel free. Very proud of myself

Comment: If you've answered your own question, you should add it as a an answer and then accept it so that other people know it works.

Comment: I do agree with this suggestion of posting your solution in the 'answers' section @TheoJones

Comment: I’ve been looking for the code, it’s deep in my files somewhere. It’s also the most horrible looking thing, so be prepared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import os
import pandas as pd
import logging
import sys
import csv
import itertools

mutations = ['A222V', 'D614G', 'E484Q', 'E780Q', 'G476S', 'L18F', 'N439K',
             'S477', 'S477N', 'T478I', 'V483A']

combinations = []
for M in range(1, len(mutations)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(mutations, M):
        combinations.append(subset)
        
        combinations = ['_'.join(sorted(x)) for x in combinations]
        combinations = [x.split('_') for x in list(set(combinations))]

root = "C:"

os.chdir(root)

lineages = os.listdir('Results')

combination_labels = []
combination_counts = []

for lineage in lineages:
    
    df = pd.read_csv('Results/' + lineage).dropna()
    
    for combination in combinations:
    
            combination_df = df[list(df)]
        
            for mutation in combination:
                combination_df = combination_df[combination_df[mutation] == 1]
    
        #print(combination_df.shape[0])
        
            combination_labels.append('_'.join(combination))
            combination_counts.append(combination_df.shape[0])
        
            out_df = pd.DataFrame({'combination':combination_labels,
                               'count':combination_counts})
            out_df['percentage'] = (out_df['count'] / df.shape[0]) * 100
            out_df = out_df.sort_values('percentage', ascending = False)   
        
            out_df.to_csv('Results_2/' + lineage.replace(".csv", "") + '_3.csv',
                     header = True, 
                     index = False)
```